# What does solid mean in playing pool

Tags: meaning

I've read a dialog about two men playing pool and I found a line that really confused me.

A: Hey, did you see that shot? I just sank three balls!
B: Yeah, **but the first one was a solid, and I'm solids**, so it's my shot now.

I don't personally play pool so I was thinking that the word solid is something to do with "pool terms". Or I thought wrong. I looked up solid and I read about playing an eight-ball. I got more confused. So is the word "solid" a "pool term" or is it just an expression? Please enlighten me. Thank you!

Comment: http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pool

Comment: In the UK I've only ever heard the two types called ***spots** and stripes*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to http://sports.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8):

In pool, the balls numbered 1-7 are called solids because the color of each covers the surface of the ball; those numbered 9-15 are called stripes because the color of each is restricted to a band on the surface of the ball.  The black 8-ball and the white cue ball are called out separately:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So what does it mean when B said, "but the first one was a solid, and I'm solids"?

Comment: One player attempts to sink solids, and the other attempts to sink stripes.  If a player sinks one of his opponent's balls, then he loses his turn.  Apparently A above is playing stripes and sank three balls with one shot.  B notes that the first ball that A sunk was his (a solid), so A loses his turn and it's B's turn to shoot.

Comment: @deadrat Many pubs have pool tables in Britain (snooker and billiards mostly confined to clubs, as they take too long for a casual game). But few play the official rules as they are not well understood. Pubs often have their own local rules. In some there is a pub rule which says that if a player has failed to pocket a single one of his colours before his opponent has pocketed all of his, he must run one circuit of the table naked from the waist down, with his trousers off! (Rarely enforced!)